# Split pandas dataframe to multiple dataframes until their respective last filled row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame to be read from excel range C54:Q66. Now there are multiple datasets in this .Please see figure.[image]

[image]

I want to read the main dataframe (Excel Range C54:Q66) once only and the split the dataframes in 4 separate dataframes like:

```
dataframe_1 = Excel Range (C54:D64)
dataframe_2 = Excel Range (I54:J64)
dataframe_3 = Excel Range (L54:M65)
dataframe_4 = Excel Range (P54:Q66)
```

Can you please recommend how to do this in Python using pandas. I know one way is to read these data frame individually from excel file but it takes a lot of time to read the file 4 times and I also know it is inefficient. I know you experts will have an efficient way of achieving this. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pandas official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html), `pandas.ExcelFile.parse` allows you to parse multiple tables in a single sheet. I mock a spreadsheet as you can see in the figure below.

[image: Example of spreads]

The following code shows how you can parse tables in the same sheet.

> **usecols: int, str, list-like, or callable default None**
>     If None, then parse all columns.
>     If str, then indicates comma separated list of Excel column letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are inclusive of both sides.
>     If list of int, then indicates list of column numbers to be parsed.
>     If list of string, then indicates list of column names to be parsed.
>     If callable, then evaluate each column name against it and parse the column if the callable returns True.
>     **Returns a subset of the columns according to behavior above.**

```py
xl = pd.ExcelFile("data.xlsx")
df1 = xl.parse(sheet_name=0, header=1, usecols=[1, 2, 3])
df2 = xl.parse(sheet_name=0, header=1, usecols=[6, 7, 8])
```

`df1` output:

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | x | x |
| 1 | y | y | y |

`df2` output:

| index | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | a | a |
| 1 | b | b | b |